# Angular 5 :-Template from api

Tags: angular

Hi i want to show the template from api in angular 5 front end and replace the `{{data}}` with another api

```
ex: {
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "first": "k",
    "last": "reddy",
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "phone": "8886345310",
    "password": "$2a$10$He2DW5Ehyz3b/LrgHN2CK.6VLM8pkk",
    "createdAt": "2018-09-08T05:50:47.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2018-09-08T05:50:47.000Z",
    "Templates": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "template1",
        "template": "<p>{{user_data?.email}}</p>",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "success": true
}
```

i have data like above and in api data **templates** i have template with html entities i want to replace `{{user_data?.email}}` this with email from the api

here user_data is the user

Comment: It is really unclear what you are asking. Can you show us some code and what template you are talking about?

Comment: suppose i have `<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>` and data is `<p>{{username}}</p>` i want to replace username with the email in json given above but its showing ternery operator as it is in the page

Comment: Hi. Are you saying that you have a default value in the HTML template then there is a call to an API and you want the default value in the HTML template to be replaced by what comes back from the API call? If that's the case, check out [ngOninit Lifecycle hook](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) in the documentation. Also if you have some code examples that would be helpful for us to assist you. :)

Comment: Can you show us the full code which is responsible for replacing the username?

Comment: `@Component({
  selector: 'app-lazy-view',
  template: '
  <div [innerHTML]="user_data?.Templates[0].template"></div>'
})
export class LazyComponent implements OnInit{
  constructor(private loginservice: LoginService) { }
  user_data:any;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.get_user_data();
  }

  get_user_data() {
    this.loginservice.get_user_data()
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.user_data = data['user']
        },
        (error) => {
        });
  }
} ` in this code this.user_data is the response given in the question